# AS3WebSocket library SHA1 error

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, websocket, sha

I am trying to use https://github.com/Worlize/AS3WebSocket library.
When I create Flex project everything ok, but when I create AS3 project it can't connect to a websocket server. Function SHA1.hashToBase64 (adobe.crypto library) inside Websocket class throws error:

```
    [SWF] TestWS.swf - 506,881 bytes after decompression

    typecheck com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$/hashToBase64()
    outer-scope = [global Object$]
    [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {} ()
    0:debugfile "/Users/turtle/work/as3corelib/project/src;com/adobe/crypto;SHA1.as"
    [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {} ()
    2:debugline 100
    [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {} ()
    4:getlocal0
    [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {} (com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O])
  5:pushscope
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  6:pushbyte 0
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (int[I])
  8:convert_u
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (uint[U])
  9:setlocal 7
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  11:debug
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  16:debug
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  21:debug
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  26:debug
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  31:debug
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  36:debug
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  41:debugline 102
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  43:getglobalscope
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (global~[O])
  44:getslot 1
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$[O])
  46:getlocal1
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$[O] String[S])
  47:callproperty com.adobe.crypto:SHA1::createBlocksFromString 1
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (Array[O])
  50:coerce Array
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (Array[O])
  52:setlocal2
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  53:debugline 103
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  55:findpropstrict com.adobe.crypto:SHA1::hashBlocks
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O])
  57:getlocal2
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] Array[O])
  58:callproperty com.adobe.crypto:SHA1::hashBlocks 1
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (flash.utils::ByteArray[O])
  61:coerce flash.utils::ByteArray
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] *[A] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (flash.utils::ByteArray[O])
  63:setlocal3
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  64:pushstring ""
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (String~[S])
  66:debugline 109
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (String~[S])
  68:coerce_s
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] *[A] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (String~[S])
  69:setlocal 4
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  71:debugline 110
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  73:getlocal3
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (flash.utils::ByteArray[O])
  74:pushbyte 0
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (flash.utils::ByteArray[O] int[I])
  76:setproperty position
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  78:debugline 111
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  80:pushbyte 0
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (int[I])
  82:convert_i
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] *[A] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (int[I])
  83:setlocal 5
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] int[I] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  85:jump 129
------------------------------------
MERGE FIRST B129:      [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] int[I] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
------------------------------------
B129:                  [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] int[I] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  129:getlocal 5
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] int[I] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (int[I])
  131:getlocal3
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] int[I] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (int[I] flash.utils::ByteArray[O])
  132:getproperty length
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] int[I] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (int[I] uint[U])
  134:iflt 89
------------------------------------
MERGE FIRST B89:       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] int[I] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
------------------------------------
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] int[I] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  138:debugline 117
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] int[I] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} ()
  140:findpropstrict mx.utils::Base64Encoder
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] int[I] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (Object~[A])
  142:constructprop 14 0
                       [com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O] String[S] Array[O] flash.utils::ByteArray[O] String~[S] int[I] *[A] uint[U]] {com.adobe.crypto::SHA1$~[O]} (*[A])
  145:coerce mx.utils::Base64Encoder
Connection Failure: There was an error while parsing the following HTTP Header line:
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: k9NwkeRGtpHKwr+kcSk29tHaAbs=
Disconnected
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the [as3corelib.swc](https://github.com/Worlize/AS3WebSocket/blob/master/AS3WebSocket/lib/as3corelib.swc) being used by that project, and ran the following code.

```
SHA1.hashToBase64('k9NwkeRGtpHKwr+kcSk29tHaAbs=');
```

In addition to your output, which basically says Flash Player threw an error trying to construct a new `Base64Encoder` object, I got the following output.

```
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.utils::Base64Encoder could not be found.
```

It seems to be a known issue with as3corelib that was never resolved.

However, this dependency is also open source, so I just downloaded [Base64Encoder.as](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/utils/Base64Encoder.as), and added it to my project. After this, the code compiled fine. This should work for your project, as well.